# Loading up separate html files before they are requested with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, external, singlepage

So I have [this](https://github.com/vectorman1/vectorman1.github.io/) as my source code and all is well, apart from when I try to load up the pages with a slow internet connection. What happens is that the current page gets faded out and back in, and after the content from the external html file is loaded it just pops in.

I'm trying to tackle this with just loading everything once the page is loaded initially, how would that work?

Main JS script link - [here](https://github.com/vectorman1/vectorman1.github.io/blob/master/js/scripts.js)

Comment: You could load the html into variables and use them as needed.

Comment: @Stef would  that look like `var home = null; home.src = "home.html";` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as a separate answer as it focuses on your current approach.

Instead of using `.load()`, use `.get()` so it isn't replacing the content of your div right away. Then `.fadeOut()` the div, replace the HTML, and `.fadeIn()` upon success.

```
$.get("news.html", function(data) {
    $("#content").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).html(data);
    }).fadeIn();
});
```

I was only able to test this with a slow connection simulator (Network Link Conditioner for Mac OS X), but it ran smoothly for my tests.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I +1nned but I have less than 15 rep so it doesn't show :)

Comment: No worries! We've all been there. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

A better method than my comment suggestion to store in variables would be to render the HTML in hidden divs and display them as needed. That way you're only rendering once.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="hidden" id="home"></div>
    <div class="hidden" id="news"></div>
    <div class="hidden" id="contact-us"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden { display: none }
```

Now use `.load()` in the background to populate the divs. I'd defer loading until the page is ready for the user so you aren't blocking user interaction. Your menu clicks would then be responsible for adding / removing the `.hidden` class from each div.

Comment: Yes but wouldn't that get a little bit too much once I present a dropdown menu with multiple things in it? Imagine all the stuff that would be in that index.html file. Madness. That's why I approached the problem the way I did. I appreciate the answer though.

Comment: @dubplay Definitely. It's not a scalable solution by any means.